# cannot adjust brightness

Tags: display, brightness, troubleshooting

I slide the brightness slider under the volume control in the upper right corner, but no avail.  I hold the fn key and tap F8 and F9 with no change in screen brightness.  Keyboard backlight control works.

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Razer Blade 15 Advanced Model *Early 2021* - RZ09-0367BEC3

I've tried the many grub editing suggestions, but none of the answers work for my situation.  I'll keep looking through the forums and keep trying suggestions.

I choose to install 3rd party software and chose the option to password protect that step, but I did not execute it correctly.  I'm thinking the issue may be there somewhere.

I am using the "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary,testd)"

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or Xorg ?

Comment: You might need to install the OpenRazer drivers for all functions of the keyboard to work. https://openrazer.github.io/#ubuntu

Comment: Are you trying to change the brightness or the backlight intensity?